# Is it considered poor programming to do this with xna components?

Tags: c#, xna

I created my own *Menu System* that is event driven.

In order to have a loading screen and multithreaded loading to work, I devised this sort of implementation:

```
//Let's check if the game is done loading.
if (_game != null) 
{
    _gameLoaded = _game.DoneLoading;
}

//This means the game is loading still, 
//therefore the loading screen should be active.
if (!_gameLoaded && _gameActive) 
{
    _gameScreenList[2].UpdateMenu();
}

//The loading screen was selected.
if (_gameScreenList[2].CurrentState == GameScreen.State.Shown && !_gameActive) 
{
     Components.Add(_game = new ParadoxGame(this));
     _game.Initialize(); //Initializes the Game so that the loading can begin.
     _gameActive = true;
}
```

In the XNA Game Component that contains the actual game, in the `LoadContent` method I simply created a new `Thread` that calls another method `ThreadLoad` that has all the actual loading.

I also have a boolean variable called `DoneLoading` in the XNA Game Component that is set to `true` at the end of the `ThreadLoad`.

I am wondering if this is a poor implementation.

Comment: Instead of polling the game to see if it's done, why not have it just fire an event when the loading thread finishes?

Comment: I am not sure how it is supposed to be done in XNA, but using a boolean flag in a multithreaded application = shooting yourself in a foot. Also `(_game != null)` is rather a parameter validation then a condition to check if the game has finished loading.

Comment: @LKIM If I use an event, regarding the Update and Draw methods of the ParadoxGame Component, how would I make sure the objects aren't use when they are not loaded?

@ oleksii I am not checking if the game has finished loading, but I am checking the state of the load boolean variable.

Comment: In your event handler you set a boolean _gaveLoaded = true. Then everywhere else, you just need to poll that value instead of continually asking the game.

Comment: @LKIM Tell me if this implementation is good: http://pastebin.com/TKak3XHK